# Stacked Bar graph with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, graphics, bar-chart

I have to do a single stacked bar graph getting the data from an API, but I am finding some issues.

1- On one hand, the data I get is not rounded, even if I use %.

2- On the other hand, the total I get is not always 100%, then the bar is sometimes a few pixels shorter and sometimes a few pixels longer than expected.

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Data } from '../../Types'

const Colors: Record<string, string> = {
    warning: 'yellow',
    good: 'green',
    danger: 'red',
}

const StackedBar = (props: {
    title?: string
    Data: Data | null
}) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <div
                style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    flex: '1 1 auto',
                    alignSelf: 'auto',
                }}
            >
                {props && props.Data ? (
                    props.Data.items.map((item) => {
                        const percentage =
                            (item.count / items_total) * 100
                        return (
                            <Rectangle
                                percentage={percentage}
                                color={
                                    itemColors[item.items_total]
                                }
                            />
                        )
                    })
                ) : (
                    <Rectangle percentage={100} color="grey" />
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default StackedBar

const Rectangle = styled.div<{ percentage: number; color: string }>`
    height: 20px;
    width: ${(props) => props.percentage}%;
    background-color: ${(props) => props.color};
`

const NormalBold = styled.p`
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: var(--font-size-normal);
`
```

Answer (score 0):

**percentage =(item.count / items_total) * 100**, here items_ total is not defined, check the code again. I think it should be item.items_total.
for rounding use Math.round(percentage) to round off values.
I think this should resolve your issues.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I have items_total defined somewhere else (it's a call from an API). How can I use the Math.round to not be more nor less than 100% in total ?